# Can't receive messages using Google Cloud Messaging for Android (not the helper library)

Tags: android, push-notification, client-side, google-cloud-messaging

Does anybody can help me with a working example for receiving messages from gcm using Google Cloud Messaging for Android. I have tried both ways (helper library and GoogleCloudMessaging class) and nothing seems to work. I'm using a PHP script that shows the following:

Multicast ID: 5.2108110103215E+18
Number of messages processed successfully: 1
Number of messages with processing errors: 0
Canonical IDs: 0

So apparently everithing is OK. I could register the device in both ways, using the helper library (gcm.jar) and using GoogleCloudMessaging class. The problem is that there is no way the message I send via PHP arrives, or at least I don't know how to handle it correctly. Here are the permissions and the receiver from my manifest:

```
<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />    
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />

<receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

Finally here is the service class

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {

private static final String PROJECT_ID = "49XXXXXXXX6";    
private static final String TAG = "GCM Intent Service";

public GCMIntentService()
{
    super(PROJECT_ID);
    Log.d(TAG, "GCMIntentService init");
}


@Override
protected void onError(Context ctx, String sError) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + sError);     
}

@Override
protected void onMessage(Context ctx, Intent intent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Message Received");

    String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");

    sendGCMIntent(ctx, message);

}


private void sendGCMIntent(Context ctx, String message) {

    Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent();
    broadcastIntent.setAction("GCM_RECEIVED_ACTION");

    broadcastIntent.putExtra("gcm", message);

    ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context ctx, String regId) {

    Log.d(TAG, regId);

    // Notify main UI to update registration status
    Intent registrationIntent = new Intent();
    registrationIntent.setAction("registered");
    registrationIntent.putExtra("regId", regId);
    sendBroadcast(registrationIntent);      
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context ctx, String regId) {
    //...

}
}
```

Here is the code when using the GoogleCloudMessaging class (I changed the manifest to use the custom receiver):

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final String TAG = "GCM Receiver";
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
private Context ctx;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d(TAG, "Message received");

    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
    ctx = context;
    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Send error: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
    }
    else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED
            .equals(messageType)) {
        sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: "
                + intent.getExtras().toString());
    }
    else {
        sendNotification("Received: " + intent.getExtras().toString());
    }
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

// Put the GCM message into a notification and post it.
private void sendNotification(String msg) {
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) ctx
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(ctx, 0,
            new Intent(ctx, MainActivity.class), 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(
            ctx).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_temp)
            .setContentTitle("GCM Notification")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(msg))
            .setContentText(msg);

    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
}
```

}

The thing is that everything seems to be ok, but the message never arrives. Any ideas??
Thanks in advance.

Comment: very nice tutorial here http://tech-papers.org/google-cloud-messaging-gcm-for-android-and-push-notifications-2/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following in your manifeast

```
 <permission
    android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="PACKAGE_NAME.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- App receives GCM messages. -->
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
```

Comment: Sorry you are right, but it was a problem when copying the manifest to the post. My manifest actually has the permissions and I updated the post. Any other idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your manifest is missing some permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" 
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcm.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

EDIT :

In your manifest you are using `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver`. That's a class from the old helper library (`gcm.jar`) which starts an intent service. If you want to use the helper library you should define the intent service in your manifest.

If you don't want to use the helper library, you should change the package of `GCMBroadcastReceiver` in the manifest to be the package of the `GCMBroadcastReceiver` class that you included in your question. Otherwise, that class won't be used.

Comment: Sorry you are right, but it was a problem when copying the manifest to the post. My manifest actually has the permissions and I updated the post. Any other idea? Thanks.

Comment: @AlejandroCasanova If you are using the `GCMBroadcastReceiver` class you included in your question, you don't need the `GCMIntentService`. However, your manifest refers to `com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver`. What's the package of the `GCMBroadcastReceiver` you included in the question? It's probably not `com.google.android.gcm` (and if it is, it shouldn't be). My guess is that your manifest refers to Google's default `GCMBroadcastReceiver`, and that's why your code doesn't work.

Comment: I updated the manifest with the missing GCMIntentService. Actually I have two examples and none of them work. The first uses the current manifest with the GCMIntentService and the helper library. I think this time nothing is missing. 
The second project doesn't use the helper library and the receiver in the manifest is as follows:

    <receiver android:name=".gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
This time with no GCMIntentService. The receiver in the 2nd example is the one in the question. Still stuck :(

Answer (score 1):

After correcting the issues above still no push messages. The problem was the 403 error. Looks like that service is not available in Cuba, so the solution is to use a tool like "your freedom" or "thor", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to change 'com.example.gcm' to your package name e.g. 'com.yourdomain.yourapp'

Comment: That is the package I used for my demo app.

Answer (score 0):

You are using GCMBaseIntentService which has been deprecated by Google. (But it should be still working.) I followed the latest tutorial http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html and did receive messages. You can try it too.

Another possible reason is you may have received a message but it was not shown in a notification successfully. Add this line in the method: sendNotification(String msg)

```
    Log.i(TAG, msg);
```